# High Chart - Loading Only after refresh in IE Edge

Tags: performance, internet-explorer

My Highchart Load in IE 10 only after I refresh by pressing f5.

Please let me know how to solve this. Mozilla and Chrome perfect.

Comment: Could do with some more detail here. Like what what HIghChart?

Comment: Created with Highstock 2.0.3 @Richard Dakin

Comment: 1) It is perfectly working in Firefox and Chrome.

2) In IE, Only work after a f5 Press. 

Any guess what is the root cause? @RichardDakin

Comment: That's an old version! I can't imagine it works too well with the more recent versions of IE. IE tends to be not be backward compatible in some areas. I think highchart back then was using VML to render which will be horrific in newer browsers. I'd honestly try upgrading